# How can I associate one of the two versions of the Telegram app on a PC to open the Telegram link?

Tags: file-association, portable, telegram-messenger

I have two versions of the Telegram app on my PC, one is portable and the other is installed. When I want to open a Telegram link through Chrome, it opens the link with the portable version of the app, but I want the installed version of the app to do this. How can I solve the problem?

Comment: @Ramhound - Well, yes, I want the installed version to do this only out of the two versions